# Error running multiple tests in Specflow/Selenium

Tags: selenium, specflow, saucelabs

I have an existing project that uses Specflow and SpecRun to run some tests against Sauce Labs. I have a `BeforeSenario` hook that creates a `RemoteWebDriver` and an `AfterScenario` hook that closes this down.

I've now moved this into another project (copied the files over, just changed the namespace) and the first test runs fine but then get the following error:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected error. The command you just sent (POST element) has no session ID.
>
> This is generally caused by testing frameworks trying to run commands after the conclusion of a test.
>
> For example, you may be trying to capture a screenshot or retrieve server logs 
>   after selenium.stop() or driver.quit() was called in a tearDown method.
>   Please make sure this process happens before the session is ended.

I've compared the project and it's using the same version of SpecFlow, same .Net version. I can't see any difference between the two projects.

In my steps I have the following line:

`public static IWebDriver driver = (IWebDriver)ScenarioContext.Current["driver"];`

which I think is the issue as instead of getting a new instance of it from the `ScenarioContext` it's using the previous test's version which has now been disposed.

But I can't see why this is working in another project instead?

I am using the Specflow example in Github [here](https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/CSharp-SpecFlow-Selenium/tree/master/SauceLabsSpecflowDemo)

**UPDATE**

Looks like I've found the issue. In the Default.srprofile the `testThreadCount` was 1 whereas the value in the working solution was 10. I've now updated this to match and it works.

Not sure what this value should be though. I assume it shouldn't be the same number of tests, but then how do I get around my original issue of the shared driver context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestThreadCount specifics the number of threads used by SpecFlow+Runner (aka SpecRun) to execute the tests. 
Each of the threads are separated. The default is AppDomain isolation, so every thread runs in a separate AppDomain.

In the SauceLab example there are 7 scenarios and the runner is configured to use 10 threads. This means, every scenario is executed in a different thread with its own AppDomain. As no thread executes a second scenario, you get this error not in the example

With only one thread, your thread is executing more than one scenario and you get this issue.

Easiest fix would be, if you remove the static from the field. For every scenario you get a new instance of the binding class. You do not have to remember it static.

For a better example how to use Selenium with SpecFlow & SpecFlow+ have a look here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest

You have to adjust the WebDriver- class for using SauceLabs over the RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for that link, that has solved my other issue about how to do Specflow tests against multiple browsers! Within Sauce Labs I can have two concurrent tests, does that mean I should set the testThreadCount to 2? What should I do about the static field?

Comment: Yes, set it to 2 and simply remove static from the field.